# Scrolling list on calendar

Tags: calendar

How do I get the scroll listing of all my events on my calendar? It is not showing up to the end of the year. It only shows a dot under the date on the monthly calendar. I had it before but it is now gone. Was there an upgrade done for the calendar?

Comment: Are you referring to iOS or OS X (on a Mac)?

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps:

Mac Os X:[image: mac calendar]

iOS:

[image: ios calendar]

Please **do not** use only capitals as it is considered impolite.